# Que signifie « array » en langage de jeunes

Tags: argot, anglicismes, langage-des-jeunes

Savez-vous que signifie *array* en langage de jeunes ?

Comment: Mot qui a été utilisé pour répondre à la question  "quel est votre âge ?"

Comment: Peut-on avoir le contexte ? (Une série, discussion dans la rue ... )

Comment: Réponse à un questionnaire anonyme

Comment: Quelle était la question ??

Comment: Le questionnaire était-il en ligne ?

Comment: Oui le questionnaire est en ligne et la question était "quel est votre âge ?". Le questionnaire est destiné à des jeunes lycéens entre 15 et 18 ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ma réponse est basée sur le complément d'informations que tu as donné.

En tant que « jeune » et française, je n'ai jamais entendu, ni lu cette réponse à la question « quel est votre âge ?»

Je pencherai plutôt pour une erreur lors de la saisie de la réponse du questionnaire qui a mené le site à transformer la réponse en *array*.

Comment: Merci ! :) Je pense que c'est ce qui s'est passé !

Comment: Ou toutes les réponses à la question affichent _array_ ce qui indiquerait peut-être un problème pas mal plus grave... ?